# How to map moon phase degree to an item in a list in python

Tags: python, coordinate-transformation, astronomy

I am using Skyfield API to calculate the phase in degree at a particular time. Phase in itself is meaningless and I want to name that phase which the degrees represent. 0° means New moon. 45° means waxing crescent.

```
moon_phases=['New Moon','Waxing Crescent', 'First Quarter','Waxing Gibbons','Full Moon','Waning Gibbons', 'Last Quarter', 'Waning Gibbons']
degrees=[0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315]
```

I want it to print New Moon even when the phase degree is 340° or 20°. What is the best approach for this? I don't want to use if else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

A simple solution is to determine how many times 45 goes into your degrees.

```
import math

moon_phases=['New Moon','Waxing Crescent', 'First Quarter','Waxing Gibbons','Full Moon','Waning Gibbons', 'Last Quarter', 'Waning Gibbons']
degrees=[0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315]

degree = 177
i = round(degree / 45) % len(degrees)
moon_phase = moon_phases[i]

print(moon_phase)
>> Full Moon
```

Or you can just wrap this into a function, such as

```
def moon_phase(degree):

    moon_phases=['New Moon','Waxing Crescent', 'First Quarter','Waxing Gibbons','Full Moon','Waning Gibbons', 'Last Quarter', 'Waning Gibbons']
    degrees=[0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315]

    i = round(degree / 45) % len(degrees)
    moon_phase = moon_phases[i]

    return moon_phase
```

Comment: 177 degrees gives Waxing gibbons instead of full moon. I need what is the nearest

Comment: I didn't see that in your description, but that makes sense. I'll edit.

Comment: We round to nearest integer instead, and that will give you the nearest phase.

Comment: I updated to include handline degrees which will wrap from the final phase back to the initial phase.

Answer (score 0):

I like a dict to map the values to names, then use function to find the closest value to lookup in the dict.
https://onlinegdb.com/0WIDlxXJJ

```py
from random import randint

mapping = {
    360: 'New Moon',
    315: 'Waning Gibbons',
    270: 'Last Quarter',
    225: 'Waning Gibbons',
    180: 'Full Moon',
    135: 'Waxing Gibbons',
    90: 'First Quarter',
    45: 'Waxing Crescent',
    0: 'New Moon'}

for test in range (10):
    target = randint(0, 360)
    closest = min(mapping, key=lambda x: abs(target - x))
    print(f'{target:>3} {closest:>3}', mapping[closest])
```